How to extract the arguments of current function in C？
I'm trying to implement a function that retrieves the call stack unwinding from the caller.
Take the following program as an example:
// test.c
void func2(int a, double b, int* c)
{
    my_backtrace_func(); // line 4
}

void func1(int a)
{
    func2(5, 1.2, 0xabcd); // line 9
}

int main()
{
    func1(1); // line 14
}

Like gdb backtrace does, My function will print stuff like this:
stack #1: func2 in test.c, line 4.
stack #2: func1 in test.c, line 9.
stack #3: main in test.c, line 14.

Now I wish to extend its functionality: Extract all the arguments of the caller, just like gdb info args does:
stack #1: func2 (a = 5, b = 1.2, c = 0xabcd) in test.c, line 4.
stack #2: func1 in test.c, line 9.
stack #3: main in test.c, line 14.

The program is assumed to be compiled with -g on ARM64, which means I have access to .debug_ sections and x0~x30 registers.
As I'm not an experienced developer of a debugger, I assume I need a parser of dwarf format, find AT_DW_location of arguments in .debug_info, maybe then refer to .debug_loc for location list or .eh_frame for DW_OP_call_frame_cfa .
However, the actual storage of parameters is changeable, and different compile levels such as -O0 and -O2 may require different processing. I don't know if this is a feasible and correct solution.
So far, I have not referred to gdb source. I guess there will be something meaningful, but it's hard for me to read.
Is there any simple and clear way to implement this? how?

I would take a look at libbacktrace.

To understand you correctly, you want to print out the stack trace from the program itself?

it could be much simpler to just system("gdb -ex 'attach <yourpid>' -ex 'gdb info args'")

@tl-photography.at True, That's why I don't use a real debugger but "reinvent the wheel" instead.


Is there any simple and clear way to implement this?

No.
To implement this, you would need to have a detailed understanding of how the debug info is encoded, and how to interpret it.

I assume I need a parser of dwarf format, find AT_DW_location of arguments in .debug_info, maybe then refer to .debug_loc for location list ...

Yes, and more. You could compile your example program, and then study the output from readelf -wi a.out.
Look for DW_TAG_subprogram, followed by DW_TAG_formal_parameters. Each parameter will have DW_AT_type and DW_AT_location, which will tell you the type and location of the parameter.

I don't know if this is a feasible

It's feasible, but by the time you are done you will have implemented 30-50% of a real debugger. At which point a reasonable question is: why not use a real debugger which exists already?
Update:


What are you trying to achieve?



I'm providing an API for collecting stack addresses. ... I want to restore the callstack information and parameters for possible debugging behaviors.

You are mixing debugging and logging. They are closely related, but they are not the same.
While logging can help debugging, logging all parameters to all functions in the call stack is

unlikely to be fast enough
isn't going to work reliably in optimized builds
isn't going to be useful, because in any non-trivial program the interesting parameters aren't going to be simple types -- they are going to be pointers (or references) to data structures, which contain pointers to other data structures, etc.  The value or the pointer is going to be useless most of the time.

If you try to solve issue#3 by printing the contents of pointed-to structures, that will only exacerbate issue#1.

The reason is: I need an api providing the "call stack" and "arguments" features, which can be called when the program itself is running. gdb is more commonly used in interactive scenarios, which can't meet my needs.

@Jordan "The reason is ..." -- no, that's not the reason. What are you actually trying to achieve? You may be falling into http://xyproblem.info

The actual reason is perfomance. I'm cooperating with others for a log system. I'm implementing a part of it: Providing an API for collecting stack addresses. The system requires extreme high performance so the address resolving will be postponed until the log is flushed to disk. After resolving I want to restore the callstack information and parameters for possible debugging behaviors.

@Jordan I've updated the answer.

For the 3 issues: 1. Log only those parameters in the first frame, like the example I mentioned in the description, that may help for speed. 2. No idea yet, I'm searching a solution make it as reliable as possible. 3. For pointers, just print the address. Whatever, the call stack itself is the main feature I focused on, while parameters are extented. I'm not pursing a 100% accurate debugger with both good performance and usefulness, so I'd be satisfied if the parameters can provide some basic information for reference.

For the given example, depending upon the optimization level used during compilation, the function1 and function2 would be inlined. Argument list cannot be found using "info args" or "info frame" for those inlined functions.
However, if you do not use optimization flags "info frame" would provide current stack frame. This would also include list of arguments.
info_args_command(const char *args, int from_tty) 

function in gdb/stack.c implements "info args" command of gdb.
Trace reference implementation for getting current stack frame using
get_selected_frame()

function in gdb/frame.c.
